# Last day of month with H2

Tags: sql, h2

How can I get the last day of a month in H2 SQL? In MySQL the following would work:

```
SELECT LAST_DAY(GETDATE())
```

Thank you.

EDIT:

Ended up with using the following:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPADD(DAY, -DAY(TIMESTAMPADD(MONTH,1,GETDATE())), TIMESTAMPADD(MONTH,1,GETDATE()));
```

The reason for this is that it also support MySQL. Just replaced the functions from Vijaykumar's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please try :

```
SELECT DATEADD(dd, -DAY(DATEADD(m,1,@Today)), DATEADD(m,1,@Today))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT day(dateadd(dd,-day(ym_next),ym_next)) last_day_of_month
 FROM (SELECT DATEADD(m,1,ym) ym_next
   FROM (SELECT parsedatetime(concat(2016,'-',2,'-1'),'yyyy-MM-dd') ym)ym)ym
```